# Is there a "Stackoverflow" notifier for Linux?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, notifications, linux

A notifier program (icon on the main panel) that would indicate when new messages / comments are received.

Features:

- Permanent Icon on the main panel
- Icon changes state when new messages for user are available
- Icon changes state when profile for user is updated
- Real-time notification
- Works on KDE and GNOME

Comment: I'm pretty sure FireFox works on Linux, too. What's your point?

Comment: @John Smithers: Cute... there is a difference between a Browser and a notifier.  I am looking for an icon that would pop on the top panel when there is a state change on my SO account.

Comment: When you float in a feature-request, build it with some tinnies and craft it so that it will be bouyant for someone to step on. In other words, have some steak and chips with it.

Comment: There is an envelope next to your name, Jean-Lou. And a notifier bar above it. Again I think these work on Linux, too.

Comment: I am talking about an OSD Notifier based application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- [StackApplet](https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-stackoverflow-meets-the-gnome-desktop-v1-2-released) for Gnome
- [StackTray](https://stackapps.com/questions/117/stacktray-the-stackoverflow-tray-application) for KDE

Apparently, they do not poll the /user/{id}/recent page. You can still feature-request this, however, on the respective project pages. :)

Comment: I highly recommend StackApplet - and I'm not just saying that 'cuz I wrote it :)